# How much can this be simplified to a select statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I am trying to gransp wether I can get big refactoring advantages out of learning LINQ.
How can LINQ improve this code, which is a real-world example that is representative for a lot of code in a project I work on:

```
foreach (SchemeElement elem in mainDiagram.Elements)
{
    if (elem.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar)
    {
        if (connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(elem.ConnectionPointId))
        {
            if (!taAddrList.TAAddressList.ContainsKey(elem.Key))
            {
                taAddrList.TAAddressList.Add(elem.Key, new TAAddress());
            }

            taAddrList.TAAddressList[elem.Key] = connPts.Busbars[elem.ConnectionPointId];                        
        }
    } // if busbar
} // foreach element
```

**For Clarity:**

`taAddrList.TAAddressList` is of type `Dictionary<ElemKey, TAAddress>`
where `ElemKey` is a two-component type that consists of two `int` ID's.

`connPts.Busbars` is of type `Dictionary<int, TAAddress>`

Comment: Try installing [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and you will get an icon in Visual Studio on the left side of your code - click it and ReSharper will convert it to Linq. Works perfectly (where it's possible), I write my queries most the way you do then use ReSharper to rebuild it automatically.

Comment: @Marc: I do have ReSharper, but this only moves the first `if` up to the foreach like this: `foreach (SchemeElement elem in mainDiagram.Elements.Where(elem => elem.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar))`. I would think there are more optimisations that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for yourself:

```
var query = from element in mainDiagram.Elements
            where element.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar
            where connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(element.ConnectionPointId)
            select element;

foreach (var element in query)
{
    // by accessing immidiatly in a dictionary (assuming you are using one), you can either insert or update 
    taAddrList.TAAddressList[element.Key] = connPts.Bushbars[elem.ConnectionPointId];
}
```

Comment: So just assigning the value to the element with specified key will automatically add if not exists?

Comment: It will, not the other way around though, trying to read an item without checking if it exists will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Well this depends, its certainly alot easier to write that sort of stuff in LINQ, but the depends part is on whether `TAddressList` is just a `Dictionary`... if it were you can get that dictionary easily:

```
var dictionary = mainDiagram.Elements.Where(e => e.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar)
              .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, e => connPts.BusBars[e.ConnectionPointId])
```

If you have to add to `TAddressList` in exactly the manner you gave in your example, you simply need to `ForEach` over the list

```
mainDiagram.Elements.Where(e => e.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar && !taAddrList.TAAddressList.Contains(e.Key))
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(e => taAddrList.TAAddressList.Add(elem.Key, connPts.BusBars[e.ConnectionPointId]));
```

Comment: This looks good, but as you said - it depends... `taAddrList` and `connPts` are `ref` parameters into my method, and I get the compile error: "Cannot use ref or out parameter 'taAddrList' inside an anonymous method body". Any way to wrap this so it works?

Comment: I think it's wrong, for same keys and different values you will accept first one but if you see OPs code he selects last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SchemeElement elem in mainDiagram.Elements.Where(r => r.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar 
    && connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(r.ConnectionPointId)))
{
        if (!taAddrList.TAAddressList.ContainsKey(elem.Key))
        {
            taAddrList.TAAddressList.Add(elem.Key, new TAAddress());
        }

        taAddrList.TAAddressList[elem.Key] = connPts.Busbars[elem.ConnectionPointId];  
} // foreach element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for selecting a list of SchemeElement:

```
var query = from elem in mainDiagram.Elements
            where elem.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar 
                  && connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(elem.ConnectionPointId)
            select elem;

foreach (SchemeElement elem in query){
    if (!taAddrList.TAAddressList.ContainsKey(elem.Key))   
            {   
                taAddrList.TAAddressList.Add(elem.Key, new TAAddress());   
            }   

            taAddrList.TAAddressList[elem.Key] = connPts.Busbars[elem.ConnectionPointId];                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = 
    mainDiagram.Elements
      .Where(e => e.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar && 
             connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(e.ConnectionPointId))

foreach (var elem in elements)
{
    if (!taAddrList.TAAddressList.ContainsKey(elem.Key))
    {
        taAddrList.TAAddressList.Add(elem.Key, new TAAddress());
    }

    taAddrList.TAAddressList[elem.Key] = connPts.Busbars[elem.ConnectionPointId];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = mainDiagram.Elements
                .Where(el => el.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar
                    && connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(el.ConnectionPointId));

            items.ForEach(item =>
                {
                    if (!taAddrList.TAAddressList.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                    {
                        taAddrList.TAAddressList.Add(item.Key, new TAAddress());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Code bellow is not tested, I assumed finally addresses want to go a specific Dictionary of Address objects, and address class contains two property, Key and value:

```
addressDic = mainDiagram.Elements.Where(x=>x.SubType == EElemSubType.BusBar)
                    .Where(x=>connPts.Busbars.ContainsKey(x.ConnectionPointId))
                    .GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
                    .Select(x=>new {Key = x.Key,
                            Value = connPts.Busbars[x.Last().ConnectionPointId]})
                    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key);
```

but as you can see, It's not very readable in linq, but depend on your power in linq, may be it's simpler than for loop.

Comment: And how do I populate this to `taAddrList.TAAddressList`?

Comment: @awe In `new {Key = x.Key,Value = x.Last()` just use your object type and instead of x.Last() select : `connPts.Busbars[x.Last().ConnectionPointId]` I'll edit it to take a sample.